# Display name in ui, access value in server for large list

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to search a large list by name in the ui and use the value in the server function.  Both the names and values are character vectors. I can't get it to pass the correct input (site_no as a character) to the server function. Here is an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(dataRetrieval)
library(tidyverse)

site_no<-c("11469550","11469500","11469570")
site_name<-c("Bear","Mat","Oil")
sites<-setNames(site_no,site_name)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("site", "site",choices = sites)),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("WY")))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  df <- reactive({
    readNWISuv(input$site, "00060", "2000-11-15", "2001-11-11",tz="America/Los_Angeles") 
  })


  output$WY <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = df(),mapping = aes(x = as.Date(dateTime,tz="America/Los_Angeles"), y = X_00060_00000)) +
      geom_line()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Do you want `sites[input$site]`? You don't have a list here, you have a named vector. Also it would be easier to test with a simple example that doesn't use functions like `readNWISuv` since that doesn't seem to be directly related to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `?readNWISuv`

> `startDate` character starting date for data retrieval in the form **YYYY-MM-DD** ...

and the same for `endDate`, but you passed these dates in terms of **YYYY-DD-MM**. The following should work

```
#Only the 1st id from the help page works
site_no<-c("05114000", "11469500", "11469570") 
readNWISuv(input$site, "00060", "2000-11-15", "2001-11-15",tz="America/Los_Angeles") %>% addWaterYear
```

Comment: I updated the above example but it still isn't running the readNWISuv function. I think `input$site` is being passed as the station_nm.

Comment: @Srizza change `site_no<-c("11469550","11469500","11469570")` to `site_no<-c("05114000", "11469500", "11469570")` as I mentioned above, none of your ids work only the one from the help page works and retrieved data i.e. "05114000".